# NON-tapered, pipe joint leaking water

Tags: leak

I am installing a mixing valve on my water heater to run water to my shop. The valve came from Europe, with adapters and rubber washers to convert to IPS, tapered joints. They are not working. How can I stop a leaking, brass, non-tapered pipe joint from leaking ?

Answer (score 1):

Non-tapered should seal with a gasket/washer.

Generally either too loose or too tight if it's leaking past the gasket (over-tightening can have unexpected results, up to and including destroying the gasket/washer.)